Bulk copying Excel into a SQL Server table copies a column incorrectly
I'm trying to do a bulk copy of the contents of an Excel sheet into a SQL Server table. The thing is, there is a column in the Excel sheet that is called ISBN, almost all the time the values are composed of numbers (always integers), but sometimes, it has some letters, like an X.
But after the bulk copy is done and I check those records that have letters in the ISBN column, the ones that have a letter are null. So, this column should be treated as a string (everything is set-up to do so but I can't find out why it does not).
Here's the code of the bulk copy function:
# Import the Excel file
public class ExcelImport
{
    private string Excel03ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";
    private string Excel07ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";

    public void Import(string filePath)
    {
        string file = filePath;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
        string conString = "";
        string sheetName = "";

        switch (extension) 
        {
            case ".xls":
                conString = string.Format(Excel03ConString, filePath, "YES");
                break;

            case ".xlsx":
                conString = string.Format(Excel07ConString, filePath, "YES");
                break;
        }

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new(conString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new(conString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new())
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                conn.Open();
                oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new();
                oda.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();
                InsertRecords(dt);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void InsertRecords(DataTable imported)
    {
        string truncateQuery = "DELETE FROM Base";

        SqlConnection conn = new DbConnection().GetConnection();

        using(conn)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(truncateQuery, conn);
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            await sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Base";

                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ISBN", "ISBN"); // This is the column that results in a null value when the ISBN has an X character
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Title", "Title");

                await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(imported);
                await conn.CloseAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}

Setting the column in the SQL Server table to varchar datatype, trying different cell types in Excel (general, number, text, custom), but this always results in a null. It does not throw an error when the ISBN does not have a letter.

The decision about the datatype is based on the values in the first few rows. Make sure the first row of the data contains a value with alpha characters.

For the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB provider,  I believe you can set option TypeGuessRows=0 to force the provider to scan all rows (instead of the first 8 by default) before deciding on a column type. The IMEX=1 option can then be added to tell the provider to read columns containing mixed data as text, instead of the majority type. For the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB provider, the IMEX option can still be used, but for some stupid reason Microsoft omitted the TypeGuessRows option. The fallback is to modify aregistry setting.  See this question.

I'd probably just manually read the data into datatable instead of using Fill. @TN, that's a very good write-up, and it explains why it's such a pain to import Excel files through SSIS and Import Wizard

Thank you all for the responses, I tried some of the things but due to network issues with the company and some other problems, the process kept giving errors, so I decided to just clone the column, and use the Excel function TEXT() to convert the values without losing anything.
